# How do I check a list of words in an if statement for my chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension and I'm using a lot of if statements to check the webpage for a list of words. And I have to continuously type each word over and over again but I'm wondering if there was a way to check the words one time through a list.

Currently I'm kinda working like this:

```
if (text == "apple")
if (text == "orange")
if (text == "Banana")
if (text == "Cherry")
if (text == "Lime")
```

and so on.. But is there a way to check a list of these words so I don't have so many if statements?

I was thinking of something like this:

```
List = "apple", "orange", "Banana", "Cherry", "Lime"

   if (text == "list")
```

Is something like this possible in a Google Chrome Extension?

Comment: Its a plain js question. Not related to chrome extensions specifically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your list of words into an array, and then you could do a simple using indexOf. For example:

```
var list = ["apple", "orange", "Banana", "Cherry", "Lime"];
```

and then you could check the list with: (Thanks to @Edwin for making it even shorter)

```
if(list.indexOf(text));
```

Comment: can be shortened to: `~list.indexOf(text)` no need for `!== -1`

Comment: @Edwin you're absolutely right, nice catch

Comment: seen this question a lot and you just edited and forgot the `~`

Answer (score 0):

You can use for to loop through it:

```
var list = ["apple", "orange", "Banana", "Cherry", "Lime"];

for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if(list[i] == text) {
        // text WAS FOUND !
        break;
    }
}
```

Hope this help !
Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = ["apple", "orange", "Banana", "Cherry", "Lime"];

var doesExist = list.some(function(word){
 return text == word;
}); //boolean

if(doesExist) {

}
```

Depends what you want to do, because in the function you can do complicated checks or whatever. But if it's something simple I'd go with the other answer with **indexOf**